# PyInstaller is creating a corrupt file

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller 3.6 and running the command `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Splash.py` and following is the terminal logs :

```
40 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
40 INFO: Python: 3.8.2
50 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.2.0-kali2-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
54 INFO: UPX is available.
56 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python',
 '/root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python']
56 INFO: checking Analysis
56 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
56 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
57 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
63 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2642 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
2642 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib/python3.8'
5487 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5588 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5622 INFO: Analyzing /root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python/src/main/python/Splash.py
6019 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
8999 INFO: Processing module hooks...
8999 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
9075 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
9076 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
9280 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
9281 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
9292 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
9292 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
9293 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
9344 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
9345 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
9436 INFO: checking Tree
9436 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
9437 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
9445 INFO: checking Tree
9445 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
9445 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
9465 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
9495 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
9501 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
9504 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_certifi.py'
9505 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
9517 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
10137 INFO: Looking for eggs
10138 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
10184 INFO: Using Python library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
10191 INFO: Warnings written to /root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python/build/Splash/warn-Splash.txt
10238 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python/build/Splash/xref-Splash.html
10253 INFO: checking PYZ
10253 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
10253 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python/build/Splash/PYZ-00.pyz
10886 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python/build/Splash/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
10894 INFO: checking PKG
10894 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
10894 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
16624 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
16630 INFO: Bootloader /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
16631 INFO: checking EXE
16631 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
16631 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
16631 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /root/Downloads/projects/wlt-retailer-python/dist/Splash
16760 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

And when I see in the dist folder, there is a file called Splash, but it is not an executable. I am doing all this Ubuntu 18 and sending my generated file to a windows 8 machine. In windows 8 it shows the type of file as simply file, not and exe. So windows is unable to recognize the file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyinstaller is not supporting cross-compiling. As stated in their documentation:  to make a Windows app you run PyInstaller in Windows

Comment: Thanks, I got to know about it pretty late, so now I am trying to package Python and its libraries on wine in my system, hope it will work with pyinstaller also on wine